# save usercontrol textbox content back to its bindingsource

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in Winforms and now got stuck; I have created a custom usercontrol for textbox as shown in the code below:

```
public partial class TextBox : UserControl
{
    public TextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtTEXT.Text = "";
    }

    [DefaultValue("Text")]
    public string Caption 
    { 
        get { return lblCAPTION.Text; } 
        set { lblCAPTION.Text = value;} 
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public new string Text
    {
        get { return txtTEXT.Text; }
        set { txtTEXT.Text = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(true),DefaultValue(100)]
    public int Caption_Width
    {
        get { return lblCAPTION.Width; }
        set { lblCAPTION.Width = value; }
    }

    private void txtTEXT_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.txtTEXT.Text.StartsWith("textBox"))
            this.txtTEXT.Text = "";
    }

    public new BorderStyle BorderStyle
    {
        get { return txtTEXT.BorderStyle; }
        set { txtTEXT.BorderStyle = value; }
    }

    public bool PasswordChar 
    {
        get { return txtTEXT.UseSystemPasswordChar; } 
        set {txtTEXT.UseSystemPasswordChar = value ;}
    }

    public bool m_Mandatory = false;
    public bool Mandatory 
    {
        get { return m_Mandatory; }
        set 
        {
                m_Mandatory= value;
                lblAMENDATORY.Visible = m_Mandatory;
        } 

    }

    private void TextBox_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Height = txtTEXT.Height;
    }
}
```

Then in another form, I have binded this textbox  as in the code below:

```
           BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    BindingSource bsDet = new BindingSource();
    DataSet data;
    SqlDataAdapter masterDataAdapter;
    SqlDataAdapter detailsDataAdapter;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        // Create a DataSet.
        data = new DataSet();

        // Add data from the Customers table to the DataSet.
        masterDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from RFID_MAS", connection);
        masterDataAdapter.Fill(data, "RFID_MAS");

        // Add data from the Orders table to the DataSet.
        detailsDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from RFID_DET", connection);
        detailsDataAdapter.Fill(data, "RFID_DET");

        // Establish a relationship between the two tables.
        DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("MyRelation",                  data.Tables["RFID_MAS"].Columns["SEQ_NO"],data.Tables["RFID_DET"].Columns["MAS_SEQ"]);
        data.Relations.Add(relation);

        // Bind the master data connector to the Customers table.
        bs.DataSource = data;
        bs.DataMember = "RFID_MAS";

        // Bind the details data connector to the master data connector,
        // using the DataRelation name to filter the information in the 
        // details table based on the current row in the master table. 
        bsDet.DataSource = bs;
        bsDet.DataMember = "MyRelation";
        // textBox1 is default Windows TextBox
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.bs, "RFID_NO", true,               DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation));
        //  textBox2 is my ouwn usercontrol textbox
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.bs, "SEQ_NO",true,                  DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation));

        dataGridView2.DataSource = bsDet;
        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();

        dataGridView2.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

        bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;
        //bs.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Then I am saving my textbox data as:

```
 this.Validate();
        this.bs.EndEdit();
        SqlCommandBuilder cm = new SqlCommandBuilder(masterDataAdapter);
        this.masterDataAdapter.Update(data.Tables[0]);
```

Now my problem here is that when I add a new record,
the data from TextBox1 (ie windows default textbox) get updated in the BindingSource,
but data from TextBox2 (ie  my own usercontrol textbox) does not get updated in the Bindingsource.

Please Help me if I am missing out something.
Very thanks to you.

Comment: Yes, I'm having this issue too with binding user controls to `BindingSource`. At last, I had to decompose the user controls and copy their contents to the form